# Baterry Indicator Not Updating

Tags: 20.04, power-management, battery, indicator

all!

For some reason my battery indicator won't change. It won't go up/down nor change from charging/not charging. The only way I can get it to update is by rebooting the machine. I've tried using the upower refresh command, and not even that will change anything.

I have an ASUS TUF F15 (2022) laptop running 20.04LTS with the 5.19.0-6.1-liquorix-amd64 kernel (necessary because of my hardware). Back when I first installed it the version was 5.17.x (iirc). Last month I updated it to the current version, though idk if that's the cause of my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!